# glmmTMB warning message

Tags: r, glmmtmb

I want to run the following model:

```
mod.1 <- glmmTMB(Step ~ Parasitised*Mixed*Week + 
         (1|Animal.ID/Group) + (1|Logger.ID) +(1|Plot),
         data = data.df, 
         family = nbinom1, 
         control=glmmTMBControl(optCtrl=list(iter.max=1e3,eval.max=1e3)))
```

I have ran the model once before and it worked fine, but when I try to run it a second time on the same computer I get the following warning message

"In fitTMB(TMBStruc) :
Model convergence problem; non-positive-definite Hessian matrix. See vignette('troubleshooting')"

Why did this model run fine on my computer once before, but show a warning sign the second time I tried to run it? Is there anything I can do to remove that warning sign that I might have done the first time I ran the model.

Comment: Have you tried setting your seed? `set.seed(10)`

Comment: No, but I will try it out. Why do you think that would work?

Comment: Just guessing, but that's the culprit sometimes for this type of issue. Seemingly identical code giving different results.